# Having problems sending multiple lights to my shader

Tags: c++, shaders, directx, graphics, hlsl

I have a lightstruct in C++ which holds the color and direction of the light.

```
    const int NUM_LIGHTS = 1;

struct lightStruct {
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
    XMFLOAT4 Direction;
};
```

And this is how I create my buffer and update it.

```
    void PBRMaterial::CreateLightBuffer(ID3D11Device* device, ID3D11Buffer** lightBuffer, std::vector<lightStruct*> lightStructs){

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc;
    cbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(lightStruct) * NUM_LIGHTS;
    cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    cbDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    cbDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = &lightStructs[0];
    InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    if (FAILED(device->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, &InitData, lightBuffer)))
    {
        throw GameException("ID3D11Device::CreateLightBuffer() failed.");
    }
}

void PBRMaterial::SetLightBuffer(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, ID3D11Buffer** lightBuffer){

    deviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, lightBuffer);
}
```

On the shader side I declare my variables as such:

```
    #define NUM_LIGHTS 1

    struct DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT_DATA {
        float4 Color;
        float4 Direction;
    };

    cbuffer cbDirectionalLight : register(b0)
    {
        DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT_DATA directionalLights[NUM_LIGHTS];
    };
```

Now, I don't get any errors but my shader only outputs black. I have been stuck on this for two days now and I can't come up with a solution. For debug purposes I also tried outputting the light's color directly like this:

```
    OUT.rgb = directionalLights[0].Color.rgb;// ambient + diffuse + specular;
OUT.a = 1;
```

But that also just shows up black.
Anyone have a thought on what the issue might be? Thanks!

EDIT:
Complete shader code:

```
    #include "include\\Common.fxh"

    #define NUM_LIGHTS 1

    struct DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT_DATA {
float4 Color;
float4 Direction;
    };

    cbuffer cbDirectionalLight : register(b0)
    {
        DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT_DATA directionalLights[NUM_LIGHTS];
    };

    float4x4 WorldViewProjection : WORLDVIEWPROJECTION; 
    float4x4 World : WORLD;

    float3 CameraPosition : CAMERAPOSITION;
    float4 AmbientColor : AMBIENTCOLOR = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

    Texture2D ColorTexture;
    Texture2D NormalMap;
    Texture2D SpecularMap;
    Texture2D GlossMap;

    RasterizerState DisableCulling { CullMode = NONE; };
    SamplerState ColorSampler { Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR; AddressU =                 WRAP; AddressV = WRAP; 
    };


    struct VS_INPUT
    {
        float4 ObjectPosition: POSITION;
        float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD;
        float3 Normal : NORMAL;
        float3 Tangent: TANGENT;
    };

    struct VS_OUTPUT 
    {
        float4 Pos: SV_Position;
        float3 Normal : NORMAL;
        float3 Tangent : TANGENT;
        float3 Binormal : BINORMAL;
        float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD;
        float3 LightDirection : TEXCOORD1;
        float3 ViewDirection : TEXCOORD2;
    };


    VS_OUTPUT vertex_shader(VS_INPUT IN)
    {
        VS_OUTPUT OUT = (VS_OUTPUT)0;

        OUT.Pos = mul(IN.ObjectPosition, WorldViewProjection);
        OUT.Normal = normalize(mul(float4(IN.Normal, 0), World).xyz);
        OUT.Tangent = normalize(mul(float4(IN.Tangent, 0), World).xyz);
        OUT.Binormal = cross(OUT.Normal, OUT.Tangent);
        OUT.TextureCoordinate = get_corrected_texture_coordinate(IN.TextureCoordinate);
        OUT.LightDirection = normalize(-directionalLights[0].Direction.xyz);

        float3 worldPosition = mul(IN.ObjectPosition, World).xyz;
        OUT.ViewDirection = normalize(CameraPosition - worldPosition);

        return OUT;
    }


    float4 pixel_shader(VS_OUTPUT IN) : SV_Target
    {
        float4 OUT = (float4)0;

        float3 sampledNormal = (2 * NormalMap.Sample(ColorSampler, IN.TextureCoordinate).xyz) - 1;
        float3x3 tbn = float3x3(IN.Tangent, IN.Binormal, IN.Normal);
        sampledNormal = mul(sampledNormal, tbn);
        float3 lightDirection = normalize(IN.LightDirection);
        float3 viewDirection = normalize(IN.ViewDirection);
        float n_dot_l = dot(lightDirection, sampledNormal);

        float4 color = ColorTexture.Sample(ColorSampler, IN.TextureCoordinate);

        float3 ambient = AmbientColor.rgb * AmbientColor.a * color.rgb;

        float3 diffuse = (float3)0;
        float3 specular = (float3)0;

        if (n_dot_l > 0)
        {
            diffuse = directionalLights[0].Color.rgb * directionalLights[0].Color.a *saturate(n_dot_l) * color.rgb;

            float4 sampledSpecular = SpecularMap.Sample(ColorSampler, IN.TextureCoordinate);
            half smoothness = GlossMap.Sample(ColorSampler, IN.TextureCoordinate);
            float SpecularPower = pow(2, 1 + smoothness * 10);

            float3 reflectionVector = normalize(2 * n_dot_l * sampledNormal - lightDirection);


            specular = sampledSpecular * min(pow(saturate(dot(reflectionVector, viewDirection)), SpecularPower), color.w);
        }

        OUT.rgb = ambient + diffuse + specular;
        OUT.a = color.a;
        return OUT;
    }

    technique11 main11
    {
        pass p0
        {
            SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, vertex_shader()));
            SetGeometryShader(NULL);
            SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, pixel_shader()));

            SetRasterizerState(DisableCulling);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

`std::vector< lightStruct* >`

to

`std::vector< lightStruct >`

Comment: This answer would benefit from an additional information on why the suggested change fixes the problem.

Comment: That’s because std::vector< LightStruct* > is a linear array of pointers to the data.
But InitData.pSysMem should be initialized with a pointer to the data.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which editor you are using, but Visual Studio contains a HLSL shader debugger. So you can select a pixel/fragment and see which DXCalls influenced the pixels color.

Start your program from Debug -> Graphics -> Start Diagnostics (or hit Alt + F5), then press „Print“ to capture the last rendered frame.

Hope that helps! If not, can you show the pixel shader you are using?

Comment: I tried your suggestion of debugging via the diagnostics but I cant capture any frames. When I press Print it keeps showing the moving blue dots.

I will edit the original post with the complete shader source.